# AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID

Tags: java, azure, api

I am following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/call-msgraph-with-username-password/) and seeing the following issue.

```
ERROR com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.PublicClientApplication - [Correlation ID: 6ed3f887-f7a7-4201-ba9c-6587d8510ef8] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'ab8dd9d6-d79b-454d-9c40-236a74cfe698' named 'AzureTestApp01'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: 0eb3ee9e-b1c1-43e8-90b3-2a1a70b71100
Correlation ID: 6ed3f887-f7a7-4201-ba9c-6587d8510ef8
Timestamp: 2020-06-19 22:32:40Z
```

I have followed the steps below:

1. Registered the app as Public client
2. updated Manifest to set allowPublicClient property to true
3. set the User.Read permission
4. also given Grant/revoke admin consent

I have referred multiple articles to resolve this; but none worked. Any pointers will be helpful. This is the code I am using:

```
PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(APP_ID).authority(AUTHORITY).build();
String scopes = "User.Read";
UserNamePasswordParameters parameters = UserNamePasswordParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(scopes),userName,password.toCharArray()).build();
IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).get();
```

Comment: I need you to provide two screenshots. 1. (Application Registration -> Your Application -> API Permissions) 2. Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to be the administrator of the tenant (if you are not a tenant administrator, you cannot give the administrator permission), you can set up user roles according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal) process.

Then follow this process to grant administrator consent to the app:

1. Log in to https://portal.azure.com as a tenant administrator.
2. Open the registration of your application in the following location.
3. Go to settings and then the required permissions.
4. Press the grant permission button.

[image]

Based on your question, I used the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)  test to get the access token.

[image]

Parse the token to see the scope of `user.read`.
[image]

Finally, to obtain user information, visit `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` Api.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Carl Zhao for your input; somehow I am getting a 400 while hitting the /oauth2/v2.0/token. I tested it using Postman, I am getting a AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password though my username and password are correct.  I came across this while researching: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30802 . Have you come across this?

I think your suggestion should fix my issue; only if I could get past this AADSTS50126 error I am receiving at the moment.

Comment: @jaykay007j Hi，I didn't encounter this problem. Is the user you use the tenant's administrator? If you are sure that your username or password is correct, you try to create a new AzureAD service account and provide it with similar access to the original service account. Test to see how.

Comment: The user is an administrator. I am using a corporate Azure AD account for testing. It has a multi-factor authentication enabled. I am not sure whether that's the reason it's not working. I am still researching on that part.